# Creating Custom Open Graph Stories Facebook?

Tags: android, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

Creating Custom Open Graph Stories is deprecated. Do we have any alternative for it.
  How can we make custom actions and objects now.

Comment: _“How can we make custom actions and objects now”_ – you can’t, because that feature was removed.